# Rails & Backbone.js - Remotipart Gem Throwing Error after... Successful Upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.js on Rails application, and I wanted to upload an image with AJAX.  What's weird is that the image is uploading to my Amazon S3, but ajax is throwing a parse error.

```
= form_for @page, :html => { :multipart => true, :data => { :type => 'json' } }, :remote => true do |f|

  .field
    = f.label :bg_image
    = f.file_field :bg_image

  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

When I click save, it uploads fine (which I know because when I refresh it shows the new image, and there isn't an error in my rails console).  However, I want to bind the new image to my backbone model, but the following just results with a `parseerror` in JS console.

```
  $("form").bind "ajax:success", (event, data) ->
    log data

  $("form").bind "ajax:error", (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    log jqXHR
    log textStatus
    log errorThrown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed `:format => :json` in my form, in order to make the action url json (this is in addition to the 'data-type' => 'json').

It was redirecting, because the html response is a redirect, hence the parseerror.